# Problem when trying to sort an array with multiple threads in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, sorting

I am new to c# and I am trying to print parts of an integer array sorted by multiple threads. For that I use bubble sort inside my function mySort which takes part of the array as a parameter and stores it to a list that I want to display afterwards. The division of the original array is in a loop where I also start the threads. The problem is that the resulting parts are all the same although I pass the different parts of the array to a function to be executed on a thread. The resulting parts includes just numbers of the last part of the original sorted array. I would be glad for any help.

```
        int[] myArray = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = r.Next(0, 100);
        }
        parts = new List<int[]>();

        Thread[] t = new Thread[5];

        int[] tmp = new int[myArray.Length/5];
        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tmp.Length; j++)
            {
                tmp[j] = myArray[k];
                k++;
            }
            Thread myT = new Thread(() => mySort(tmp));
            t[i] = myT;
            t[i].Start();
        }
```

Function for sorting

```
static void mySort(int [] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
                {
                    int tmp = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        parts.Add(arr);            
    }
```

EDIT:

By declaring tmp array inside for loop the problem is solved.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int[] tmp = new int[myArray.Length/5];

            for (int j = 0; j < tmp.Length; j++)
            {
                tmp[j] = myArray[k];
                k++;
            }
            Thread myT = new Thread(() => mySort(tmp));
            t[i] = myT;
            t[i].Start();
        }
```

Comment: Can you share some sample input and output you are getting?

Comment: Each thread is doing the same thing - `mySort(tmp)` - on the same state (there is only one `tmp`); did you intend for each thread to sort a different *portion* of the same array? or to sort a different array each? or...? if so: you need to declare `tmp` **inside** the `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`. Note that in real scenarios, you'd want to do this without creating lots of copies of the array - you'd want each thread to look at the *same* array, but a different range

Comment: You can use multiple threads to sort an array with the [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) library: `myArray = myArray.AsParallel().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();`

Comment: I intended to sort the different portion of the same array by each thread by copying that portion to a tmp array.  However, the tmp array where I copy values of the original array must be declared inside the for loop as you say. Thank you much, it works now. 

I did not want to use any libraries in order to learn how threads work but I will definitely use it in my next projects, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Be aware also that `List<T>` isn't safe for concurrent access. Those calls to `Add` inside `mySort` could easily corrupt the list.

Comment: So is there a better structure for that? Or is it good to store the array as a member of a class?